# display portion of textbox in listbox in C#

Tags: c#

I have a textbox and a listbox in my c# forms application. What I want to do is that the user will enter the query in the textbox and I want to display the portion of that query into my listbox.

For example: 
[image]

Here, I want to display "att1" and "att2" in my listbox named "Query Options"(i.e. listBox1). How can I do that?

This is the code I have written until now:

```
  private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string x = (sender as Control).Text;
        listBox1.BeginUpdate();
        try
        {
            XmlDocument xdata = new XmlDocument();
            xdata.Load("C:\\Ankush\\Visual Studio Project\\Query Info.xml");
            XmlNodeList qlist = xdata.SelectNodes("information/QueryInfo/Query");

            for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (listBox1.Items[i].ToString().ToLower().Contains(textBox1.Text.ToLower()))
                    listBox1.SetSelected(i, true);
                foreach (XmlNode node in qlist)
                {
                    listBox1.DataSource = xdata;
                    listBox1.Items.Add(node.InnerText);
                }
            }
            //listBox1.DataSource = xdata;
            string cmdstr = @"select * from information_schema.columns where table_name = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem + "'";
            string conStr = @"Data Source=INPDDBA027\NGEP;Initial Catalog=Dev_Server;Integrated Security=True";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdstr, conStr);
            sda.Fill(dt);
            listBox2.DataSource = dt;
            listBox2.DisplayMember = "Column_Name";
        }
        finally
        {
            listBox1.EndUpdate();
        }

    }
```

Please Help.

Comment: I don't know why you have to make your own query builder, but you have to define keywords, query structure for your query builder, and then process input string to get keyword, data fields ...

Comment: I didn't quite get you

Comment: Be prepared when the first user will write: Delete from xyz

Comment: I guess you need a SQL parser. See [Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.aspx).